# Can you define a sin function given two points on its graph?

Tags: functional-analysis

In other words I`m searching for a function of the form $f(x) = a*sin(bx)$ with real constants a,b.
Can you determine (a,b) given two points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$ on its graph?
(I think this is solvable because you have two variables of freedom in the function and two restraints yielding a single possibility.)
It leads to the following system of equations:
$$
 a*sin(b*x_1) = y_1 \\
 a*sin(b*x_2) = y_2 
$$
From the second I extract a (extracting b makes things worse it seems) :
$ a = \frac{y_2}{sin(b*x_2)}$
Which when substituting into the first equation yields:
$y_2 * \frac{sin(b*x_1)}{sin(b*x_2)} = y_1$
I am stuck here atm and cannot find a way to solve for b in this situation.
(Is there a simplification for the division of sines in general?)
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It may be that the only way to find $a,b$ is via numerical methods, e.g., Newton's Method.

Comment: All in all, $(a,b)$ will not necessarily be a unique solution.

Comment: I don't believe this can be solved uniquely, since you're simultaneous equations are nonlinear. If you think about constructing sinusoidal functions you should be able to construct non unique functions which share multiple points on their graphs however they could have different periodicity.

Answer (score 1):

The periodicity of $\sin$ obstructs there being a unique solution to this in general. For example, if we're given $(0, 0), (\pi/2, 1)$, then $a = 1, b = 4n + 1$ works for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Scaling can make this problem carry over to a large set of values. Note also that no solution exists in the special case of a point $(0, y)$ with $y \neq 0$, as well. To have hope of a unique solution, one needs to bring in extra constraints (such as that $a \sin(bx)$ be monotone on $(x_0, x_1)$ for instance, which then makes $\arcsin$ a helpful tool).

Comment: Can you further elaborate on an example of another constraint? and, how can we obtain an expression for all a/b that satisfy the loose constraint of two points?

Comment: why delete answer here? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2887057